# Oil dipstick: Is the distance between the 2 markers an international standard?

Tags: engine, oil, motors, dipstick

Is the quantity of motor oil represented by the distance between the bottom marker and the top marker of an engine dipstick an international standard?  If so, how much oil does it represent?

In other words, is there a standard amount of motor oil that it takes to go from the bottom marker of an motor oil dipstick to the top marker?

Comment: My guess is no. I think it'll differ for each engine based on the engine's design. As I've understood it, the bottom marker is commonly referred to as the "fill line" where if the oil is below that mark then you have to top up your oil. And the top marker is the "full line", where you shouldn't fill past that mark. And of course, anywhere in between the two marks is considered "okay".

Comment: English (american) is 1 quart, metric is 1 liter

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is an international standard, but for my car the volume to be added to go from the low mark to the high mark is 1 litre. 1 litre is 1.76 imp. pints (or 2.113 pints over the pond...)

Whether this is always true is questionable as some engines have a larger sump than others due to their design and number of cylinders...

Comment: One quart/liter was true for every car I've seen. A bigger sump would just have a shorter distance between marks.